# Monitoring of a library with sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following code to test using sinon:

```
var req = new MultiPartUpload({
    client: client,
    objectName: "/" + obj.func.destPath(),
    stream: obj.outStream,
    headers: headers
  }, function (err, body) {
    obj.debug('uploaded' + body);
  });
```

I have to test the creation of this object. How can I do it? I have tried with:

```
var MultiPartUpload = require('knox-mpu');
var stub = sinon.createStubInstance(MultiPartUpload);
instance(obj, function () {
  expect(stub).to.have.been.called;
  done();
});
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Any suggestion? Thank you :)

EDIT:

instance is the istance of the object that creates the MultiPartUpload object. The problem is  that the instance signature cannot be changed and that the MultiPartUpload library is required in the file where instance is created.

**In short:** I have to spy the MultiPartUpload library, and the problem is that is not possible to communicate in any way with istance, where the library is used.

Comment: sorry, I've edited the question to answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make it work that I found was this: instead of having:

```
 var MultiPartUpload = require('knox-mpu');
```

In the instance code. I changed it to:

```
MultiPartUpload = require('know-mpu');
```

Then in the test-case I simply put:

```
MultiPartUpload = sinon.spy();

instance(obj, function () {
  expect(MultiPartUpload).to.have.been.called;
  done();
});
```

Any way to do it better than this? (I don't like global vars). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Creates a new object with the given function as the protoype and stubs
>   all implemented functions. The given constructor function is not
>   invoked

This mean that `sinon.createStubInstance(MultiPartUpload);` will return a new stub with all prototype functions as stubs. I think you looking for a way to spy if the `MultiPartUpload` function was called, so one way could be to overwrite `MultiPartUpload` with the stub:

```
var MultiPartUpload = require('knox-mpu');
var stub = sinon.stub().returns(sinon.createStubInstance(MultiPartUpload));
MultiPartUpload = stub;
instance(obj, function () {
  expect(stub).to.have.been.called;
  done();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it doesn't work, it answers: "expected stub to have been called at least once, but it was never called"

Any other idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into something like https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module ? When you require the **instance** module, you could use SandboxedModule to substitute a spy for **knox-mpu**.

**Edit**: I can't give a complete working example, because you haven't given us all your code. But sandboxed-module works something like this:

```
var SandboxedModule = require('sandboxed-module')
  , MultiPartUploadSpy = sinon.spy()
  , expect = chai.expect
  , YourInstanceModule = SandboxedModule.require('your-instance-module', {
      requires: {'knox-mpu': MultiPartUploadSpy}
    })

instance(obj, function () {
  expect(MultiPartUploadSpy).to.have.been.called;
  done();
});
```

Comment: uhm and how would you use it? I've never used it, but using for example the code given in the README, I see that mysql is fake, but how would you spy on it to see whether has been called or not?